# Не могу получить chat id из web app telegram

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, aiogram, web-apps

есть

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    print("start")
    global id_user
    id_user = message.from_id
    group = message.chat.id
    print(group)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("открыть страницу", url="https://perevyazko1.github.io/testprojectwebappbot"))
    await message.answer(f'Привет {message.from_user.full_name}', reply_markup=markup)
```

который отправляет онлайн кнопку для открытия приложения
и есть web приложение

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const app = window.Telegram?.WebApp;
    const [appData, setAppData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAppData = async () => {
            if (window.Telegram && window.Telegram.WebApp) {
                const app = window.Telegram.WebApp;
                await app.ready(); // Убедитесь, что app готов перед обращением к initDataUnsafe
                setAppData(app.initDataUnsafe);
            }
        }
        fetchAppData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
                <p>
                    Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >

                </a>
                <div>{appData?.user?.first_name}</div>
                <div>{appData?.chat?.id}</div>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

в котором я не могу получить идентификатор группового чата.
Пробовал также запустить в чате бота, в этом случае appData?.user?.first_name получаю данные, но идентификатор чата не получаю.
Резюмирую, подскажите как при запуске веб приложения получитьидентификатор группового чата?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что тебе просто надо получать ID группогого чата и его сохранять куда-то?

Comment: Да, все верно, надо получать ID группогого чата и его сохранять его во фронте